# Why my html h1 tag change auto color when i run my web page?

Tags: html, css

I'm write this h1 tag in my web site page:

```
<h1 align="center" style="direction:rtl;color:white" >تطابق مشترکین ADSL شرکت های PAP</h1>
```

every thing is ok, but when i run the web page after 2 second change h1 tag color automatically to black!
what happen?

for first time:
[image]

after 2 second:
[image]

Comment: you should provide information in which browsers you have tested your code snippet. Else, nobody knows for sure how to reproduce this...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely another CSS file / object was loaded to override it. Maybe a javascript file as well. User a browser inspector to analyze your css to determine where the CSS is being set. Also try adding !important to your inline css.

`<h1 style="margin:auto; direction:rtl; color:white !important;" >تطابق مشترکین ADSL شرکت های PAP</h1>`

Comment: i use this javascript file <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
         <script>window.jQuery || document.write('<script src="js/vendor/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"><\/script>')</script>
         <script src="js/main.js"></script>

Comment: Ok then if your js is basic and you know there isn't anything changing the class. Then add the !important and you it should stay white.